# Dynamic query formula nested inside an array

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a query formula in Google sheets that updates based on additional columns of data in my Google Sheet seen here `=QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, C where C contains 'http'",)`

So it may add `QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, E where E contains 'http'",)`and then it will end up becoming the below and so on for each additional.

```
=QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, C where C contains 'http'",);QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, E where E contains 'http'",)
```

What I am trying to do is have the resultant query formula which is in cell 'List'!A1 as `QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, C where C contains 'http'",);QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, E where E contains 'http'",)` be used in an array formula as a reference so I don't have to update the formula each time a new query formula is added.

The static query formula is

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, C where C contains 'http'",);QUERY('Deals List - URL Split'!A:DZ, "select A, E where E contains 'http'",)}),1,TRUE,2,TRUE)
```

and indeally the one that gets the dynamic formula would be like below but I always get an error and get just the literal static formula above.

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA({'List'!A1}),1,TRUE,2,TRUE)
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: As player0 asks, please share a sheet, using this guide: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en  Working on any Sheets question is almost always easier if we can see the data structure and sample data, as well as other logic in your sheet.

Comment: But if I understand your question you want to search a variable number of columns (or just C and E?) for the text "http" and return all matching entries from column A.  Is that correct?

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12N8czjDV2T4BTKukKqHyeGHw9gFY6xRjuG2qtzCbkek/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @kirkg13 basically in my workbook above the sheet '5 QUERY FORMULA' is dynamically updated and the query formula is returned in to the red cell on that sheet.

That query formula is then located in the red cell on '6 ITEMS AND URLS' within the array. 

Since the formula updates automatically based on what is imported into the workbook I am trying to make it so that query formula is automatically pulled from '5 QUERY FORMULA' red cell and put within '6 ITEMS AND URLS' red cell between the array. 

I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what is it that you want to achieve. Why not use `IMPORTDATA` and then apply a formula to the newly imported data? Maybe I misunderstood your goal - would you mind providing more information? @jnjustice

Comment: @ale13 the links and URLs it is getting are from an API and the names and URLs are actually not shown how I've got them, they're all jumbled together which is why splitting it in stages seemed to work okay since I am not the most technical. Here's how the API starts out (and then it continues to list each item).

https://i.imgur.com/Q7CZeDu.png 

the item name is title and the URLs are within regular text in terms_conditions

Comment: Rather than doing a split on your data, and then building complicated formulas to figure out column ranges, I'm sure an expert with REGEXEXTRACT could extract all URLs from column G in your IMPORT tab.  So the product name from IMPORT!E, and any associated URLs from IMPORT!G.  Would this work for you?

Comment: yeah, that would make things a lot easier. For some reason the first tab was protected but I removed that. the URLs seem to be within some HTML as `<a href='https://www.amazon.com/Nintendo-Switch-Neon-Blue-Joy%E2%80%91/dp/B07VGRJDFY/'` but I am unsure how to tell it to find all of the `a href` and then get the values between each '

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer (or two) for you.  After looking at your sheet, I have to say that I am sure that a simpler design is possible for your sheets, that would simplify everything.  Anyway, I've built one formula, using only your data on sheet '2 URL SPLIT'!, and the desired columns from '4 URL FILTER'!A1:1.  See my sample tab, GK-6 ITEMS AND URLS, added to your sheet.

The formula, reduced to its basic form, is:

```
={
IFERROR({'2 URL SPLIT'!$A$2:$A, INDIRECT(INDEX(
  {ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR("'2 URL SPLIT'!" 
   & TRANSPOSE('4 URL FILTER'!1:1) 
   & TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
      {"2:" 
       & TEXTJOIN("~2:",1,TRANSPOSE('4 URL FILTER'!1:1))},"~",0,0)) 
       & ROWS('2 URL SPLIT'!A:A)))},1,0))},{"",""})
}
```

The formula is not truly dynamic, but it ignores blank columns.  So the cheat I've used is to expand the capacity of the formula to include extra blank columns, and if they get filled with data, the data will be used.  I've set it to include 50 columns of data, where you are currently using 39, but you could expand it to handle about 200 columns, before it reaches the 50,000 character limit of a cell.

The formula as shown above handles one column.  For the one that handles fifty columns, as in my sample sheet, I simply duplicate the inner formula, everything inside the outer braces "{....}" and increment the number in it.  You only need to do this once, or copy mine from my sheet.  You do not need to update if/when your data columns expand.

I'm happy to add much more explanation if you decide that this formula works for you.  But the basis of the formula is dynamically building the ranges of cells to query.  The result of this inner part of the formula is shown below. Note that the 2 in each range is hard-coded, and can be changed if your structure changes, but the limit of the range is calculated from your data.

[image]

The rest of the formula uses an index into this "table", incrementing by one to select each successive data range, which adds a new column of data to be queried.  These data ranges from '2 URL SPLIT!' include column A and one subsequent data column, as specified in '4 URL FILTER'!A1:A, and are stacked one above the other, by using a ";" separator.

The query is then run against this vertical, two column stack, selecting all rows where column 2 contains "http".

The final result is shown below:

[image]